# GAE + GWT + Restlet -- Which edition of Restlet should I use?

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, restlet

I'm in the process of writing a GWT based app that will talk to a Restlet-based API hosted on GAE.  I think I need to keep all of this in a single Eclipse project and a single hosted GAE app to make things work well and not have issues with single point of origin (cross-site scripting).

So... which version of restlet should I use?  I need the GAE version to get my API working on GAE, but I need the GWT version to get my UI to compile with GWT.  I must be missing something really basic here, as this is the basis of the Restlet "getting started" example app.

Am I supposed to be splitting things into multiple projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been working on their Getting Started tutorial as well, and it's no walk in the park. However, I can at least answer your immediate question: you need both editions. All of the libraries in the `/war/WEB-INF/lib` directory come from the GAE edition and will be deployed with the server. However, you also need `org.restlet.jar` from the GWT edition in your `/lib` directory. It's only used for compiling the GWT stuff, so it does not need to be in the `/war` directory, no matter what Eclipse tells you.

Comment: Yup, this was indeed the trick.  I stumbled upon the same answer last night.  Would have been more obvious if I'd started from the sample app :).  I had started down the road of separating into two different apps, but that got really hairy quite fast with all of the single source issues...